# What is the minimum interval allowed for calling List Payment API

Tags: square-connect

One of our cafes has a coffee station where the barista needs to see orders (payments) as they come in from the the registers. We are not able to use the Webhooks feature because it does not allow us to filter based on location and register and our volume is too high. So I am developing an iOS app which will periodically call the payments API for that specific location to get the latest transactions. It will use the begin_time parameter to get txns since the last query. The app will only be deployed only on one device and we would like to make the call in intervals of every 5-10 seconds. It will probablly pull down 1-3 txns for each call. Is there a minimum interval that is recommended or enforced?
Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

The only minimum interval you would have to worry about would running into rate limits, but at that rate, you won't have any problems. You can read more about error codes (including rate limiting) on [Square's official documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#type-errorcategory)

Comment: So I am now calling the payments api every 5 seconds and using the time from the previous call as the begin_time for the next. For some reason, I miss a transactions periodically. I don't specify an end_time, so do you think it could be due to a difference in time between the server and the time that my app is using? Or is it possible that a payment can show up after I have already queried for that time frame? I'm using the default sort order,

Comment: well, just thinking about network latencies, 5 seconds isn't too long. I'd poll for payments made during the last half hour, or hour and just pay attention to ones that you haven't seen before.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be working much better so far.